# How can i know total number of index available in a Windows index.wim file using DISM on the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, dism

I want to know the total number of index available in a install.wim file located in windows source using dism and store that number in a numeric variable in same dos batch script. So far I have tried below commands in a batch.

```
 for /L %%A IN (1, 1, 20) Do (
 PAUSE
 dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7x64\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%%A | Find "ProductType : WinNT" > H:\SCM\VERCHK.TXT 

 FINDSTR "ProductType : WinNT" "H:\SCM\VERCHK.TXT" > NUL
 IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 set /A INTINDEX+=1
 START H:\SCM\VERCHK.TXT
 )
 cls
 ECHO %INTINDEX%
 pause
```

I will like to mention that I am trying to complete the above process in my Windows 10 Pro x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got my answer and this is what i will do to get my desired result.

```
 @echo off

 if exist %TEMP%\scm (RD %TEMP%\scm /S /Q)
 md %TEMP%\scm

 for /L %%A IN (1, 1, 25) Do (

 dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:h:\research\Win7\InstallWin7_aio\sources\install.wim /index:%%A > %TEMP%\scm\%%A.txt
 timeout 0 >nul
 Find /i "Error:" "%Temp%\scm\%%A.TXT" > nul && (
      set "Index=%%A"
        goto:next
 ) 
 )

 exit/b

 :next
 set /A Ti = %Index% - 1
 ECHO There are %Ti% number of indexes in the image.

 pause
```

Comment: add this to clean up the temp files created here  del %TEMP%\scm /F /S /Q
rmdir %TEMP%\scm